# concatenation of strings and the null character(\0) explanation required

Tags: c

Now in this program I tried to concatenate two strings but when I don't provide null character to it's end it produces a unknown value at the end. Now I know the importance of null character but I would to know what happened here to produce the random value at the end of concatenated string and what it is?

**First code: With null character inserted**

```
void main(){
    char str1[10],str2[10],output_str[20];  
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;  
    printf("Insert first string: ");
    gets(str1);
    printf("Insert second string: ");
    gets(str2);  

    while(str1[i] != '\0')
        output_str[k++]=str1[i++];
    while(str2[j] != '\0')
        output_str[k++]=str2[j++];

    /*This the line which matters*/
    output_str[k]='\0';

    puts(output_str);
}
```

**Input:** First string: Bhushan
              Second string: Mendhe

**Output:**
BhushanMendhe

But for the same above code with the same inputs, if I just remove **'The line which matters.'** in the code.

**Output is:**
BhushanMendhe**0♥↕@**

I want to understand why that bolded part in second output was produced when we didn't specify null character and what is it called?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have typos here `while(str1 != '\0')` and here `while(str2 != '\0')`?

Comment: I think what you mean in the conditions of the loops is : `while(str1[i] != '\0')` and `while(str2[j] != '\0')`

Comment: The observed behaviour is independent form concatenation. Try this `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { char s1[4] = "abcd"; char s2[5] = "efgh"; puts(s1); }`

Comment: `♥↕@` I guess that means it loves you...

Comment: @alk yes i meant exactly what you said and i have edited it. Thank you!

Comment: "Now I know the importance of null character" -- are you sure? The `puts()` function expects a pointer to the first character of a _string_, which is defined as a null-terminated character array in C. That is to say, the `\0` itself is _part_ of the string; without a null-terminator, a character array is not a string at all. Also, [never use `gets()` in real code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Answer (score 2):

puts() reads the given memory address until it encounters an \0, if you did not specify an \0 it just continues to read the memory (which is some random garbage, probably from the last program). After a certain amount of memory it encounters an \0 and stops reading. If you did not put a \0 at the end you are in danger of running into a segmentation fault.

Comment: Or simply put, you invoke *Undefined Behavior* passing a non-null-terminated string to a function expecting a nul-terminated string as its argument.

Comment: Thank You very much. I understood what you wanted to say and i agree with you. @DZDomi